# PHPUnit Mock Multiple Expectations

Tags: mocking, phpunit

Coming from a background in Google Mock, I'm surprised this doesn't work, unless I'm doing it wrong.

I just want to ensure that a method is **never** called with a **specific class type** but may be called for other class types.  So here is the code I have that explains what I want:

```
$this->entityManagerMock
      ->expects($this->any())
      ->method('persist');
$this->entityManagerMock
     ->expects($this->never())
     ->method('persist')
     ->with($this->isInstanceOf('MySpecificClass'));
```

Now I get a message similar to this:

```
Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::persist(DifferentClassType Object (...)) was not expected to be called.
```

When I'd expect that first expectation to handle it.

I tried this but the result was the same:

```
$this->entityManagerMock
      ->expects($this->any())
      ->method('persist')
      ->with($this->anything());
$this->entityManagerMock
     ->expects($this->never())
     ->method('persist')
     ->with($this->isInstanceOf('MySpecificClass'));
```

This is my first time using mocks in PHPUnit but it seems to me that `with` is broken and/or not useful.  I know that most web developers these days use TDD so there has to be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a work-around you can use [`returnCallback`](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/test-doubles.html):

```
$this->entityManagerMock
     ->expects($this->any())
     ->method('persist')
     ->will($this->returnCallback(function ($object) {
         self::assertNotInstanceOf('MySpecificClass', $object);
     }));
```

Comment: I suppose that's not a bad idea since the assertion still tests it and I wasn't even using `will`. Thanks, although I do wish that the above code would work still, I'll accept this for now.